# How can i have relationship with relation between entities in symfony2 doctrine2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have this complex relation

```
`School` has one to many with  `rules`
`Games` has many to many `rules`
```

`Games` has no relation with `School`

But for every school , same game has diff rules

ie. i need to have table with three ids

`school_id , game_id , rule_id`

So far i have only able to have relationship with two entities but i don't know how to have three entities in a relation

Suppose if i have simple relation with `game` and `rules`.

i.e  `S1 has R1 R2 R3`

AND `S2 HAS R4 R5 R6`

Now game Suppose `G1 for S1 has is linked to R1 R2 and for S2 linked to R4 R5`

The porblem i am getting is whe i edit the data for any school , then doctrine first deletes the all other values for all schools and then insert the new ones.

ideally it should only update the avlues for that school only

Answer (score 0):

Entity School has one or many rules.

Entity Rules has one Game.

You don't need to have a relation between game and school.

You can easily have different games with different rules for a school.

If you need game rules for a school, you'll just have to find which entity rules has a relation with your school AND with your game.

Looks perfect. :) Tell me if I (or you) missed something.

Comment: Entity rule has many to many with game not one . that was just example